# Service worker : add an offline page working on localhost not on server

Tags: reactjs, apache, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've followed [THIS sample](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/) in order to make a service worker which returns an offline page.

```
// Incrementing CACHE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force
// previously cached resources to be updated from the network.
// the cache version gets updated every time there is a new deployment
const CACHE_VERSION = 0;
const CURRENT_CACHE = `main-${CACHE_VERSION}`;

// My offline page :
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';

const self = this;
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE);
      // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the
      // response isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from
      // the network.
      await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: 'reload' }));
    })()
  );
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
      // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
      if ('navigationPreload' in self.registration) {
        await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
      }
    })()
  );

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
          // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported.
          const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
          if (preloadResponse) {
            return preloadResponse;
          }

          // Always try the network first.
          const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request, {
            mode: 'no-cors'
          });
          return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
          // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
          // due to a network error.
          // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
          // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
          console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);

          const cache = await caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE);
          const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          return cachedResponse;
        }
      })()
    );
  }

  // If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't intercept the
  // request. If there are any other fetch handlers registered, they will get a
  // chance to call event.respondWith(). If no fetch handlers call
  // event.respondWith(), the request will be handled by the browser as if there
  // were no service worker involvement.
});
```

And all is working perfectly locally with my React SPA. When I set "Offline" on the network tab in DevTools I can see my offline page which reloads every 10 sc :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>You are offline</title>

    <!-- Inline the page's stylesheet. -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #0c0c0d;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-family: monospace;
      }
      button {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        min-width: 64px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
          box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,
          border 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1.75;
        border-radius: 4px;
        letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: #009e9e;
        color: white;
        padding: 1vmax;
      }
      button:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%),
          0px 4px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(0, 110, 110);
      }
      .reco {
        margin-top: 2rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>No Connection</h1>
      <button type="button">Reload</button>

      <div class="reco">
        Page will reload in <span id="timer">10</span>sc
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Inline the page's JavaScript file. -->
    <script>
      // Manual reload feature.
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });

      // Listen to changes in the network state, reload when online.
      // This handles the case when the device is completely offline.
      window.addEventListener('online', () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });

      const TRY_INTERVAL = 10;

      let timer = TRY_INTERVAL;
      let timerId = 0;
      function tick() {
        timer--;
        if (timer <= 0) {
          checkNetworkAndReload();
          timer = TRY_INTERVAL;
        }
        document.querySelector('#timer').textContent = timer;
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      }

      // Check if the server is responding and reload the page if it is.
      // This handles the case when the device is online, but the server
      // is offline or misbehaving.
      async function checkNetworkAndReload() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('.');
          // Verify we get a valid response from the server
          if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 500) {
            window.location.reload();
            return;
          }
        } catch {
          // Unable to connect to the server, ignore.
        }
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      }

      checkNetworkAndReload();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is how I register the SW :

```
navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        console.log('SW update found');
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all tabs for this page are closed'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
```

But when I'm pushing this code online it fails ... I can see the offline page rendering but the page always reload itself. The network tab is full of request and makes the navigator (chrome) almost bug ...

Can't tell what's going on ...

My server is running on Apache2,
I'm running a React Single Page Application,
Desperately trying to get the PWA `beforeinstallprompt` without success !

**You can see the problem "live" here : https://spacecheap.idontcare.fr**

The problem in action :

[image]

Comment: I just looked at the live version you provided, and it seems to work OK for me, the page makes the fetch request every 10 seconds, and reloads when the network comes back online. Is it possible you've got an old version of offline.html cached? Can you remove the service worker, clear the cache and try again?

Comment: Wow ... I always unregister and delete site data to try this... But ... It works without even deleting cache... I suppose I should have wait some minutes... Maybe my server didn't send me the right file immediatly or an old version was stored somewhere in routers ?... Thanks btw

Comment: @PeteLe ERRATUM ... It doesn't work ... Well not each time ! See the question I've updated with a video

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior, it doesn't reload the page for me. Try opening it in an incognito window, that'll make sure you're giving it a fresh test. I suspect your offline.html is being cached somewhere and is giving you problems.

Comment: The `beforeinstallprompt` event isn't firing because Chrome can't find your icons. Open DevTools > Application > Manifest, and you'll see the don't show up there. I'd recommend you change the paths to absolute paths. I'd also recommend changing the `start_url` to `/home`.

Comment: Hum ... It seems to be working on incognito mode on my PC... But as I suspected my PC... I tried on my cellphone and have reproduced this behaviour IN incognito too ! :( ...

Comment: on the offline page, right at the end, you are calling checkNetworkAndReload() instead of tick()
change it and it should work

or so i thought, but i tested both, and they work when i manually copy the offline file you put here... so im not sure whats going on, cant reproduce